# Configuring custom Gradle plugin for settings.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am writing a custom Gradle plugin that is to be applied in `settings.gradle.kts` file. The plugin is compiled using `includeBuild` in `pluginManagement` in `settings.gradle.kts`.

**Plugin and it's extension code:**

```
abstract class MyFooSettingsPluginExtension {
    abstract val myPropertyToConfigure: Property<String>
}

class MyFooSettingsPlugin : Plugin<Settings> {

    override fun apply(target: Settings) {
        val extension = target.extensions.create("fooSettingsPlugin", MyFooSettingsPluginExtension::class.java)

        println("String property: ${extension.myPropertyToConfigure.get()}")
    }
}
```

**Giving it an ID:**

```
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        register("my-foo-plugin") {
            id = "my-foo-plugin"
            implementationClass = "com.example.MyFooSettingsPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

**settings.gradle.kts:**

```
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("./build-src/my-foo-plugin")

    repositories {
        * * *
    }
}

plugins { id("my-foo-plugin") }

configure<com.example.MyFooSettingsPluginExtension> {
    myPropertyToConfigure.set("bar")
}
```

Running this setup gives me an error:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'my-foo-plugin']
> Failed to apply plugin 'my-foo-plugin'.
   > Cannot query the value of extension 'fooSettingsPlugin' property 'myPropertyToConfigure' because it has no value available.
```

If I set convention for `myPropertyToConfigure` property:

`extension.myPropertyToConfigure.convention("default property value")`

prior to using it in plugin code then everything runs fine and I get the expected output:

`String property: default property value`

Am I using this wrong or is there a bug?

I'm running this using Gradle (from gradle-wrapper) v.7.5.1

Comment: Gradle must first call `MyFooSettingsPlugin.apply()` _before_ executing any logic in your `settings.gradle.kts` file. So the property won't have a value. If you put some `println()`s in your scripts and plugins, it might make it more clear. You could use [`gradle.settingsEvaluated {}`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#settingsEvaluated-org.gradle.api.Action-), but this is [not usually a good solution](https://blog.mbonnin.net/my-life-after-afterevaluate).

Comment: @aSemy in this particular case I need this plugin to be applied exactly where it is - at the very beginning of processing `settings.gradle.kts` file, before other `includeBuild("/path")` instructions, because for my purposes those need to use output of this plugin I am asking about.